# Use JNI library in Servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, java-native-interface

I'm working on a web application but I need to call certain proprietary C++ library functions. As I understand native methods are not thread safe, it is therefore possible that an access Violation in native code can crash application server JVM. (Tomcat). This native API is very small part of the overall web application functionality, I would say only 5% of users will ever access this functionality. No matter how thorough application is tested ( I don't have access to native source code), there is a risk of a potential bug in native library can bring down whole application server logging out users and potentially downtime.

So the question  - which strategy is better?

1) Should I wrap native library in a separate process so that main web server is not impacted by a bug in native code. I can probably use UNIX sockets to communicate to this separate process from my web server. ( Avoiding overhead of TCP socket). If this happens fix the problem as quickly as possible and accept downtime for 5% of users.

Or

2) Bite the bullet and continue to use JNI in servlet container. ( With a risk of potential downtime for everyone)

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: "native methods are not thread safe" -- not true!  They are either thread-safe or not, depending on the design.  Also you can wrap non-thread-safe methods in synchronized java facades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends:

Take into account, that if a function is not thread-safe, that not necessarily means that it will crash if called from multiple-threads. It might simply return completely wrong results.

1. If your application cannot overcome it somehow, then you have no other options, you need to serialize access to the native code.
2. If you are sure that the only side-effect of calling the not-thread safe function is that it can crash, then you need to make sure that the crash does not results in other type of errors, like inconsistent data in your application in the back-end (database corruption, etc.). (You may use transactions to prevent this.)
3. If your application is able to overcome all of the above, then a 3rd piece of information is still needed:
   You need to study how much downtime/crash your users tolerate. If they tolerate the possible down-times, then go ahead and do not care about the crashes, you can safely "bite the bullet", because it won't harm your users or your application.

In all other cases you have to serialize access to the native functions.

Wrapping them into a process might be a good idea, but you have to make sure that the function(s) can be run ONLY in one thread at a time. So probably you need to implement some mechanism to make the other threads/servlets wait until one of them finished calling the function(s).